# How to produce an ANOVA matrix with R

Tags: r, statistics, anova, ggally

I've the following dataset:

```
Minutes <- rep(0:10, each=5)
Minutes <- factor(Minutes) 
Subject <- rep(1:5,time=11)
Measurement <- rnorm(55, mean=40, sd=7)
df <- data.frame(Subject, Measurement, Minutes)
```

I want an ANOVA matrix with p-values (like the following) that testing "Measurement" over "Minutes" :

```
         Minute0 Minute1 Minute2 Minute3 Minute4 ... Minute10
Minute0
Minute1
Minute2
Minute3
Minute4
...
Minute10
```

any ideas? GGally allowing this?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of result you expect. In particular, this seems dubious from the statistics perspective.

Comment: During the endurance experimentation I introduced some stressors at defined time points. Thus, I want to compare modification of my variable minute by minute. http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v11/n3/full/nmeth.2858.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pairwise.t.test {stats} function in which you specify the response variable, and then the categorical explanatory variable containing the factor levels you want to be compared, separated by a comma

```
pairwise.t.test(Measurement,Minutes)
```

Comment: It's what I want! Thanks... Now I try to improve graphical stuff! Well done!